# Fractional pole residue calculation

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

According to m.l.boas, one can solve integrations involving a simple pole using residue theorem and using those principles, I can solve integrals like

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}x dx$$

Converting to $$\frac{e^{iz}}z$$ and calculating residue at origin .

But what to do when we encounter something like a fractional pole .

If I am to do

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{x^q}}{x^q}dx$$

Then we get a laurent series at origin with fractional power by converting to a complex integral in a similar way . How to proceed with such integrals ?

Apart from way of making use of residue theorem, I am looking for a way of solving this integral, too .

**q may be a fraction**

Comment: there is no such a thing as a fractional pole - one of the fundamental properties of holomorphic and meromorphic functions is that their special set (zeroes/poles) is discrete with all points of integral order (positive for zeroes, negative for poles); truly fractional powers (e.g square root) have non-discrete singularities in the plane and are not holomorphic/meromorphic on punctured discs but only on cut discs by say a ray (or analytic arc) through the origin

Answer (score 2):

Converting to $\dfrac {\sin z^q}{z^q}$ and using the Taylor series for sin, we get:  $\dfrac1{z^q}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{(z^q)^{2n+1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{z^{2nq}}{n!}$.  Thus the function is analytic.

Comment: Indeed. @OP - note this is a straightforward generalization of $\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$ by a simple change of variables $z^q \to z$ (since both go to zero simultaneously and the integrand is clearly analytic elsewhere). We have a removable singularity at the origin.

Comment: This is fine, but how can i proceed with the integral in complex plane ? That wont be possible in the way it was done for sin(x)/x, i mean, converting it to e^(ix)/x

Comment: Shouldn't you have converted it into $\dfrac{ \sin z}z$?

Comment: Then also it will not have a residue, the dx term, in terms of new variable t=x^q, shall have fractional powers and hence residue theorem wont be applicable .

Comment: As pointed out,  there are no fractional exponents.

Comment: what if q is a fraction ?

Comment: @user157588 Let me clarify what Chris was saying - there *can* be fractional exponents (with work we can define any complex exponent, but we have to be very careful what we mean and watch for branch cuts) but there *can not* be poles or zeros of fractional order; it is a theorem of complex analysis that every singularity is either removable, a pole, or essential. Removable singularities have no sense of order, and essential singularities are essentially order $\omega.$ Poles and zeros are essentially the same construct, just with a pole being a negative integer and zeros a positive integer

Comment: If $q$ were fractional,  we would apparently have a branch cut.